# Building Kivy-ios with OpenSsl support

Tags: ios, openssl, kivy

I'm trying to build kivy-ios and include openssl. I followed the previous posts on Kivy user's group, and did the following steps:

1. Uncommenting the line that executes build-openssl.sh in build-all.sh
2. Copying Setup.dist to kivy-ios/src/python_files/Setup.dist
3. Cloning to https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl
4. Uncommenting and changing the SSL variable to pint to the right location.

I tried with the already built libraries in Cloning to ios-openssl. But when I try to build kivy-ios, I get a linking error about "_SSLv2_method". Any idea about what might be causing this? Any help is appreciated.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_SSLv2_method", referenced from:

      _PySSL_sslwrap in libpython2.7.a(_ssl.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [python.exe] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cloning to https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl
>   ...
>   Any idea about what might be causing this?

Sefan is pretty sharp, and I would not be surprised if he configured OpenSSL with the option `no-ssl2`.

You should open the file in question (perhaps `PySSL_sslwrap.c`) and wrap the offending code like so:

```
const SSL_CTX* context = NULL;
...

#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SSL2

  /* Some code to select SSLv2 only */
  context = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv2_method());

#endif
```

The offending files (like `PySSL_sslwrap.c`) should also include `<openssl/opensslconf.h>` to ensure they pick up the configuration correctly.

Since POODLE, you might also have to do it for the various `SSLv3_method`. The define of intetest is `OPENSSL_NO_SSL3`.

Here's an example of a modified [SSLscan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sslscan/) that does the dance around SSLv2 and SSLv3 if they are not present: [Modified SSLscan](http://pastebin.com/K36KEEj3).

It also detects if TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 are present with the following. TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 was added at OpenSSL 1.0.1 (`OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER` value `0x10001000L`).

```
#if !(OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x10001000L)
# define SSLSCAN_NO_TLS1_1
# define SSLSCAN_NO_TLS1_2
#endif

/* OpenSSL was config'd with 'no-ssl2' */
#ifdef OPENSSL_NO_SSL2
# define SSLSCAN_NO_SSL2
#endif

/* OpenSSL was config'd with 'no-ssl3' */
#ifdef OPENSSL_NO_SSL3
# define SSLSCAN_NO_SSL3
#endif
```

---

> Any idea about what might be causing this?

The final "any ideas" is to be sure you are linking against the OpenSSL library (`-lssl -lcrypto`, in *that* order). I'm pretty sure you are. If you were not, you would be getting boatloads of undefined symbols, and not just that one.

---

**EDIT**: this is pretty obvious (now)...

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

You project is building for x86_64, not iOS. My guess is you created an OS X project in Xcode, and not an iOS project.

I'm not sure why you did not get a slew of undefined symbols, though. Usually you get hundreds of undefined symbols.